# How to remove one charachter from a string

Tags: java

With the scanner I want to read the index of a char and then remove it from the string. There is only one problem: If the char comes multiple times in the string, .replace() removes all of them.

For example I want to get the index of first 't' from the String "Texty text" and then remove only that 't'. Then I want to get index of second 't' and then remove it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String text = "Texty text";
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int f = 0;
   int x = 0;
   while(f<1){
   char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i<text.length();i++){

      if(text.charAt(i)==c){

        System.out.println(x);
        x++;
      }
      else{
        x++;
      }

    }
  }
   System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: " while(f<1)" is always true

Comment: I can't tell how your question relates to your code. You want to replace the first `t` and then the second `t` and so on, and currently (you claim) it replaces all `t`(s). **How**? You don't use `replace` in this code. And I ran it. If you remove the infinite `while` loop and enter `t` you get: 3\n6\n9\nTexty text (where `\n` is newline). What did you **want**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Texty text";
        String copy = text;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            text = copy;
            System.out.print("Enter a character from '" + text + "': ");
            char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)) == Character.toUpperCase(c)) {
                    System.out.println(c + " was found at " + i);
                    text = text.substring(0, i) + "%" + text.substring(i + 1);
                    System.out.println("After replacing " + c + " with % at " + i + ": " + text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a character from 'Texty text': x
x was found at 2
After replacing x with % at 2: Te%ty text
x was found at 8
After replacing x with % at 8: Te%ty te%t
Enter a character from 'Texty text': t
t was found at 0
After replacing t with % at 0: %exty text
t was found at 3
After replacing t with % at 3: %ex%y text
t was found at 6
After replacing t with % at 6: %ex%y %ext
t was found at 9
After replacing t with % at 9: %ex%y %ex%
Enter a character from 'Texty text':
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
System.out.println(text.replaceFirst("t", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using txt.substring(x,y)

x = usually 0 , but x is first start index
y = this is what you want to delete for example for the last word of string write this code:
txt.substring(0, txt.length() - 1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying indices, it is possible that you may want to replace the second of a particular character.  This does just that by ignoring the ones before it.  This returns an `Optional<String>` to encase the result.  Exceptions are thrown for appropriate situations.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace the first i
        Optional<String> opt = replace("This is a testi", 1, "i", "z");
        // Replace the second i (and so on).
        System.out.println(opt.get());
        opt = replace("This is a testi", 2, "i", "z");
        System.out.println(opt.get());
        opt = replace("This is a testi", 3, "i", "z");
        System.out.println(opt.get());
        opt = replace("This is a testi", 4, "i", "z");
        System.out.println(opt.get());
    }

    public static Optional<String> replace(String str, int occurrence, String find, String repl) {
        if (occurrence == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("occurrence <= 0");
        }
        int i = -1;
        String strCopy = str;
        while (occurrence-- > 0) {
            i = str.indexOf(find, i+1);
            if (i < 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("insufficient occurrences of '" + find + "'");
            }
        }
        str = str.substring(0,i);
        return Optional.of(str + strCopy.substring(i).replaceFirst(find, repl));
    }
```